# SQL: I want to extract data from second table. As column names of second table matches with values Separated by comma of first table column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table1 with one column with values seperated by comma **firstname,lastname**. I have a table2 with two column names **firstname and lastname**, which match with table1's single column values(**firstname,lastname**). My necessity is  I want to extract data from table2 by using select statement `SELECT firstname,lastname FROM table2`. I used variables to write query.

I transferred values of table1(**firstname, lastname**) to `@link` variable and this operation completed successfully. But when i tried to add `SELECT @link FROM table2` to the query i thought i would get data of **firstname and lastname** of table2, But result showing a seperate no column name and value in that column as **firstname,lastname**.

Tons of Thanks for any help!

```
declare @link nvarchar(max)
    select @link = (select [column]
    from [dbo].[table1])
    from [dbo].[table2]
    SELECT @link FROM table2
```

Comment: Can you share some samples from your input tables and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: I don't understand what the final result you want is, but it sounds like you can join these two tables together with `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table1] t1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[table2] t2 ON t1.column = t2.firstname+','+t2.lastname`. Does that help?

Comment: "and this operation completed successfully" - No it didn't, not the way you think. You declared a variable that can hold a single `nvarchar` value. Then you assigned a whole column to that variable. A column can hold multiple values.  Second, when you select a variable directly, like `select @link`, you're just getting the value of the variable repeated for every row. It's just like selecting a literal value, for example, `select 'hello world'` would return a single row, with a single column, with the value "hello world". You might want to take a few more lessons on your sql syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be attempting "dynamic sql", i.e. you build a string that contains a select statment, then execute that string as a query. Conventionally you will find many example that use `@sql` for this, and the basic fom of this is as follows:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @sql = N'select [column] from [dbo].[table1]'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note that the @sql contents has to be valid sql syntax. On this point your code contains 2 `from` clauses and that is NOT valid, plus it isn't clear what you intended, perhaps it was meant to be a join.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @sql = N'select t.[column], j.[column2]
from [dbo].[table1] as t
inner join [dbo].[table2] as j on t.id = j.fk'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```